# How to send data back from parent component when component is being used multiple times on page

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the scenario in Angular 6.

1. One upload component which is being used two times on the same page.
2. When clicking on add button of any upload component using behavior subject, I am able to get the data for that particular upload component.
3. Once data is uploaded successfully, I would like to return a message to that particular upload component from where data was sent.

The structure is something like as follows.

```
MainComponent 
UploadComp1 UploadComp2    //These are instance of UploadComp
```

Please how to send data back from MainComponent to

1. UploadComp1 when the request is raised from UploadComp1.
2. UploadComp2 when the request is raised from UploadComp2.

In short, a component which is used for uploading a file. We are using two times on the same page, Basically, this uploadcomponent gathers the file and send to parent component, parent component uploads it.

Once uploading is being done, we would like to send the message to that particular upload component from a parent from where the file was uploaded.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear to me! Can you add more explanation to the question

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Added more info in bottom of the question

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz?

Comment: Use `@ViewChild` decorator to get the reference of your upload components

Comment: @MukeshKumar You can use `@Output() data: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();` and then 
`data.emit('<data to send>')` to send data back to parent.

Comment: Why does the upload component need a `BehaviorSubject`? What do they share? If both of them have local state, you won't have any problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a message property on the upload component, you can get a reference to your child component in the parent using @ViewChild and then set the property you want.

Since you have multiple upload components on your parent, you can tag them in your html template like `#uploadComp1, #uploadComp2,` etc then refer to them with `@ViewChild('uploadComp1'), @ViewChild('uploadComp2')`.

here is the documentation for [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator